# jq how to get a return value based on condition

Tags: linux, jq

So I'm trying to figure out how to get the `"CPU"` value based on the condition from the value from `"Tags"`...`"Value"`

So I want to print the `"CPU"` value if the value within the Tags is `NO`
The return value on this example would be: `"Identifier-0002"`

Here is the data:

```
{
  "LIST": [
    {
      "CPU": "Identifier-0002",
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Key": "Family",
          "Value": "X"
        },
        {
          "Key": "Available",
          "Value": "NO"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "CPU": "Identifier-0001",
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Key": "Family",
          "Value": "X"
        },
        {
          "Key": "Available",
          "Value": "YES"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like below. This basically checks inside `LIST`, to see if any of the objects' value is `NO` and get its `CPU` value.

```
jq '.LIST[] | select(.Tags[].Value == "NO")? | .CPU'
```

Comment: Great! You could also use `jq '.LIST[] | if .Tags[1].Value == "NO" then .CPU else empty end'`